# Syntax error while multiplying by a constant in sql

Tags: sql, count, syntax-error

I have a table `review` as follows:

```
review
--> stars           (int) 
--> business_id     (varchar)
```

I want to write a query that, given a `business_id`, extracts the number of `stars` with value= `5` corresponding to this `business_id`, multiplies them (the number of stars thus obtained) by `100` and returns the output.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT stars
        FROM   review AS r
        WHERE  r.business_id = "OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ"
               AND r.stars = "5") * 100;
```

I get a syntax error :

> Error: near "*": syntax error.

I don't undertand. If I choose not to multiply by `100`, and just return the number of `stars` with value=`5`, that is if I do :

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT stars
        FROM   review AS r
        WHERE  r.business_id = "OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ"
               AND r.stars = "5")
```

it works perfectly.

How should I correct my syntax so that I can multiply correctly?

Note that `OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ` is just a random `busines_id`.

Comment: Try SELECT COUNT(*) * 100 FROM ...

Comment: thanks. That works for me!

Comment: why would someone downvote this? I started learning sql just recently, and am trying my best to understand it.

Comment: @jac Let's say that I also wanted to divide the above result by the number of stars corresponding to the given business_id. How would I do that?

Comment: in other words, I need to divide the above result by the output of count(*) from (select stars from review as r where r.business_id="OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ")

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In (standard) SQL `"OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ"` refers to a column name, it's not a character literal. And numbers should never be enclosed in quotes (whichever type). If `stars` is defined as a number, then compare it to a number, `and r.stars = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not Multiplying numbers with 100 instead you are trying to multiply with row returned from sub query. 
You can have a try with below Query. Hope it helps you

```
SELECT Count(*) * 100
FROM   (SELECT stars
        FROM   review AS r
        WHERE  r.business_id = "OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ"
               AND r.stars = "5")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
stars INT,
business_Id VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @table (stars, business_Id)
VALUES (5,'OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ')

INSERT INTO @table (stars, business_Id)
VALUES (5,'OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ')

select COUNT(stars) * 100
from @table
where business_id='OqKuUkYMCWShOHOspYLGZQ' and stars=5;
```